# Visual Foxpro Application UI Automation

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ui-automation, visual-foxpro

I have a 3rd party Visual Foxpro application that I want to automate from .NET. The idea is to get the events like button click or change of label text triggered in .NET application.

I've tried to do this by hooking global system events in .NET using EnumChildWindows of the app, but the problem is most of the controls like labels and controls inside a pane are owner drawn in VFP, so it doesn't have handles (hWnd) to make this work.

I have read about automation via OleDB and COM interops, but the issue is I don't have any control over the source code of the VFP app. And since am very new to VFP I don't have any idea about where and how to start with.

Any pointers on this will be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickHofman yeah I know, but it doesn't mean people don't use these applications anymore.

Comment: Indeed. Just to make sure. You said you were new to it, so I wanted to make sure you invested your time correctly.

Comment: I am new as in, I don't know the architecture of it to resolve my issue or proceed in the right path.

Comment: Instead of trying to automate interaction with the forms, you can use the underlying data and create your own UI with .Net.

Comment: @CetinBasoz the existing app is very vast and all I want is to add a small functionality to it.